# Is there an ANY "escape" in Swagger

Tags: swagger, jsonschema

I have a REST API where legal JSON submitted to an endpoint will contain a sub tree depending on a "type" declaration in the top level. Something like:

```
{
   ...
   "mtype": "http:...",
   "content": {
      .. what goes here is what would be defined by the above "mtype"
```

Essentially, the 'mtype' is the schema url for what goes into 'content'. But what I'm looking for is the equivalent of `<xsd:any>`.

It would already be useful if I can put something in there which would instruct the Swagger UI to simply put a large text box there for users to paste a JSON body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can return an object of type `object` with no properties as a response.  It's not best practice but it can serve your purposes

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Swagger that well, but I know it's type definition is based on JSON Schema.  In JSON Schema, the equivalent of `<xsd:any>` is `{}`.  The empty schema validates as `true` for any valid JSON.  I expect this should be no different in Swagger.